# How to read and take average of multiple table files in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

So that's how two tables look like

```
5113.440  1     0.25846     0.10166    27.96867     0.94852    -0.25846   268.29305     5113.434129
5074.760  3     0.68155     0.16566   120.18771     3.02654    -0.68155   101.02457     5074.745627
5083.340  2     0.74771     0.13267   105.59355     2.15700    -0.74771   157.52406     5083.337081
5088.150  1     0.28689     0.12986    39.65747     2.43339    -0.28689   164.40787     5088.141849
5090.780  1     0.61464     0.14479    94.72901     2.78712    -0.61464   132.25865     5090.773443
```

that's the other table

```
5113.450  1     0.25846     0.10166    27.96867     0.94852    -0.25846   268.29305     5113.434129
5074.769  3     0.68155     0.16566   120.18771     3.02654    -0.68155   101.02457     5074.745627
5083.350  2     0.74771     0.13267   105.59355     2.15700    -0.74771   157.52406     5083.337081
5088.520  1     0.28689     0.12986    39.65747     2.43339    -0.28689   164.40787     5088.141849
5090.820  1     0.61464     0.14479    94.72901     2.78712    -0.61464   132.25865     5090.773443
```

and i know i can read them and can take their average by using the following command:

```
df1 = pd.read_table("with_blaze.ares",skiprows=0,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')
df2 = pd.read_table("without_blaze.ares",skiprows=0,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')

df = df1 + df2
```

But i have several hundred table files like these. So i want to know how can i read them together and then take their average. And the number of rows are not same in all the files, like some have 600 but other have 540 only. So how can i take the average of rows on the basis of first column in  the table???

Comment: You have 100 filenames? Is there any structure to their naming?

Comment: Are all of the files stored in the same folder? Does the folder only contain the files you want to read, or is there some naming convention among the files you need to read, like the all end with `.ares`

Comment: yes all the files have same extension and they're in the same directory.  @ALollz

Comment: No they don't.! Number of rows are different in all the files. Some have 600 rows while others have 550/540. So what i want to do is to take the average of the rows on the basis of column 1 because its same in all files.

Answer (score 3):

Concatenate all of the files into a single `DataFrame` and then use the `wave` value to group and calculate the mean.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path_to_files = 'something'
lst = []
for filen in [x for x in os.listdir(path_to_files) if '.ares' in x]:
    lst.append(pd.read_table(path_to_files+filen, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),
                             names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],
                             delimiter=r'\s+'))
df = pd.concat(lst, ignore_index=True)

# Calculate the average based on the first column
df.groupby('wave').mean()
```

---

As per your comment, you can first sort the DataFrame, so that the highest value occurs first, and then drop duplicates, leaving you with only the row for the highest `stlines` value for each unique value of `wave`. Just change the loop to:

```
for filen in [x for x in os.listdir(path_to_files) if '.ares' in x]:
    df1 = pd.read_table(path_to_files+filen, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),
                        names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],
                        delimiter=r'\s+'))
    df1 = df1.sort_values('stlines', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('wave')
    lst.append(df1)
```

Comment: voilà.! it worked, thanks for the help. I got one question though? What can i do if a row(element in column 1) is repeated in the table and out of them i just want to keep the ones whose value is higher in column('stlines')???

Comment: @astroluv Would this be for removing a row in the individual files, before joining them together into one big DataFrame? What column determines the duplicate, is it just `wave` still, or a combination of columns?

Comment: Yes it's the wave column that determines the duplicate and yes to remove the row in which the values of stlines column is smaller.